# Is there support the Yaskawa CSDA 10f (dual arm robot) with ROS?

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The yaskawa CSDA 10F(dual arm robot)  looks very similar to the Motoman SDA 10F. They also use the same controller FS100. I would like to know if I can integrate ROS with it? If so can I use the motoman_driver for the integration. and how do I go about it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249548/is-there-support-the-yaskawa-csda-10f-(dual-arm-robot)-with-ros?/) by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-07**:
First thing to make sure is whether you have / can get `167352-1` on the controller. That is a hard requirement. Apart from the driver, it'd also need a proper URDF for the CSDA10. I haven't checked, but it could be that joint limits are different from the standard SDA10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although we have never tested the clean room robots with the MotoROS driver, I don't know of any software changes from a standard FS100 controller.  I fully expect that the CSDA should be fully compatible.

As gvdhoorn mentioned, you will need part # 167352-1 installed on your controller to ensure the software is properly configured to support the MotoROS driver.  This is a Yaskawa America part number, so it can be ordered by contacting techsupport@motoman.com or +1 937 847 3200.  If you are outside of North/South America, your local office might have an equivalent part number (but you can still contact the US office).

Additionally, as gvdhoorn mentioned, you will need a proper URDF file for this robot.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble locating the data sheets for the CSDA10F, as I don't think we have sold this particular arm in the US.  I recommend that you compare the dimensions of your arm to the standard SDA10F datasheet here: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/366775/Blog_Robots/SDA10F.pdf?t=1481054766982
If you require more detailed drawings, please request these from the Tech Support team.

-Yaskawa America Inc, Motoman Robotics Division

---

Originally posted by [millete](https://answers.ros.org/users/28748/millete/) with karma: 101 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-07**:
Link to European page about the CSDA10F: [here](http://www.motoman.co.uk/en/products/robots/product-view/?tx_catalogrobot_pi1%5Buid%5D=3037&cHash=c42efbce73dd11be3ee17913ec63d2fa).

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2016-12-08**:
From what I have noticed apart from the difference in the coatings for the clean room application, there doesnt seem to be much of a difference. In that case can I just use the URDF and move it package form the SDA 10F?I have also contacted techsupport for the MotoROS software package. Thanks a ton

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-08**:
You could perhaps use the URDF, but the link geometry seems to be rather different compared to the SDA10. You should probably at least re-do the meshes.

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2016-12-08**:
Thank you, I will do that. I only see small 2cm changes in links of the arms, I will redo them. One last silly question, here I only have access to 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on a Virtual Machine. Is that acceptable or are there a few things i should be wary of? Thanks a lot for your quick responses

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-08**:
VMs are known not too work too well, especially not when doing visualisation-intensive things (RViz, Gazebo, etc). For simple robot models and tasks it may work, but you might run into issues. A dual-boot is highly recommended.

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2016-12-13**:
Thanks a ton guys .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-13**:
Please keep us informed of your progress.

Also: if you have an updated URDF for the CSDA10, I would appreciate it if you would consider contributing that to the ROS-Industrial [motoman_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman_experimental) repository.

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2016-12-13**:
Yes I will for sure. I will also add the URDF on the above mentioned repository when I am done with it.

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2016-12-14**:
Just to double check, from what I see, I guess the indigo branch has the best support for the SDA10f. So I will go ahead using ROS Indigo?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-14**:
For the SDA10 there shouldn't be too much difference between Jade and Indigo, but Indigo is probably a good idea, yes.

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2016-12-15**:
I have decided to change the axis b and axis t stl files in the URDF of the motoman SDA10 f with meshes from the CSDA10F. Apart from them , I dont see much of a change that would affect kinematics of the robot . Suggestions?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-15**:
We should probably move this discussion to the `moveit_experimental` repository issue tracker. But to answer your question: it's not just about kinematics. Robot geometry (shape, size) is also important. Not just for visualisation, but for collision avoidance as well.

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2017-01-06**:
Understood:) I am working on URDF but havent been able to find technical drawings for the CSDA10F , i have also contacted techsupport and no reply yet. I have posted it as an issue in the motoman_experimental repository